# How can I display successfully a result to a form field, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, split, dom-events

I don't know exactly how to set the results after using the `split()` function; however, I think there's something wrong with the declaration. Also, the innerHTML might not be appropriate to set the results in the textarea form element.

Here's the js code:

```
function splitNumber(){
    var number = document.getElementById("pNumber");
    var res  = number.split(" ");


    document.getElementById("aCode").innerHTML = res[1]+res[2]+res[3];


    document.getElementById("aNumber").innerHTML= res[5]+res[6]+res[7]+res[8]+res[9]+res[10]+res[11];

}


function start(){
    var splitButton = document.getElementById("split");
    splitButton.addEventListener("click", splitNumber, false);
}

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

I have to place the script in the header of the HTML document.

This is the HTML doc:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Telephone Number</title>
<linkrel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="style.css">
<scriptsrc="NumberProcessing.js"></script>     
</head>

<body>
<h1>T Number</h1>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="thistable">
   <td>Enter a phone number<br/>
    [in the form (555) 555-5555]</td>
   <td><input id="pNumber" type="text" /></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr class="thistable">
   <td><input id="split" type="button" value="Split" /></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="thistable">
   <td>Area code:</td>
   <td><textarea id="aCode" rows="1" cols="4"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="thistable">
   <td>Number:</td>
   <td><textarea id="aNumber" rows="1" cols="9"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
 
 </tbody>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function splitNumber(){
    var number = document.getElementById("pNumber").value;

    document.getElementById("aCode").value = number.substr(1, 3);
    document.getElementById("aNumber").value = number.substr(6,8);

}
```

No need to split it up. Use substr() to get the pertinent parts.

Comment: What about if I need to use the split() function?

Comment: Then you're going to have to learn RegEx's and split that string on every character since there is no unique character between every item you want returned.

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting by space, so you will end up with this two element array: [(555), 555-5555]

Do this instead:

```
var number = document.getElementById("pNumber").value;

document.getElementById("aCode").innerHTML = number[1] + number[2] + number[3];


document.getElementById("aNumber").innerHTML= number[5] +  number[6] + number[7] + number[8] + number[9] + number[10] + number[11];
```

Comment: 5 is the wrong index to start at for the second half of the number, as well, the assignments look ugly. Check in to substr();

Comment: What about if I need to use the split() function?

Comment: Yeah, innerHTML did not work with the form element "textarea", instead value was the right property to use, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer using the split function three times.

```
function splitNumber(){
    var number = document.getElementById("pNumber").value;
    var res = number.split(" ");
    var res1 = res[0].split("");
    var res2 = res[1].split("");

    document.getElementById("aCode").value = res1[1] + res1[2] + res1[3];
    document.getElementById("aNumber").value = res2[0] + res2[1] + res2[2] + res2[4] + res2[5] + res2[6] + res2[7];
}
```

I know, it doesn't look good, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

When using split you can simply do

```
document.getElementById("aCode").value = res[0];
document.getElementById("aNumber"). value = res[1];
```

As it will cut the string at the given separator and return an array with the separated substrings.

Comment: Yeah, innerHTML did not work with the form element "textarea", instead value was the right property to use, in this case.

Comment: Ok, fair point. So question was more about setting the value than the split. Adjusted my answer to reflect correct code.